# Terminology of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

I am trying to get a better understanding of the terminology of differential equations. As I understand it, I can characterize differential equations along different categories:

(i) linear vs. nonlinear
(ii) separable vs. nonseparable
(iii) homogeneous vs. inhomogeneous
(iv) ordinary vs. partial

First of all, is it useful to think in these categories?
Are there any relations among these categories? For example, is there any attribute in one category which rules out a particular attribute in another category?

Comment: One of my favorite mathematical quips is "Classification of mathematical problems as linear and nonlinear is like classification of the Universe as bananas and non-bananas." The distinction "homogeneous/inhomogeneous" doesn't make much sense outside of the linear context. The "separable" in "separable ODE" and "separable PDE" refer to two completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason students are introduced to these terms in an elementary course in differential equations is that they serve as a clue to what methods may be needed to solve the equation.

When learning how to find the derivative of functions in a beginning calculus course one finds that one only needs a dozen or so differentiation rules to find the derivative of just about any type of commonly encountered function. But when the student takes a course in the integral calculus, they realize that it is not so simple as just learning a dozen or so rules. Solving integral equations involves techniques and approaches as well as rules or formulas. One learns techniques such as partial fraction decomposition, trigonometric substitution, integration by parts, etc. and must gain some experience to understand when to attempt which method or technique. It is not so simple as just plugging into a formula.

With differential equations it is more of the same. In fact the term "integral" is broadly defined as "the solution of a differential equation."

In a course on differential equations students learn which methods are useful for solving certain frequently encountered types of equations. Giving those types a name makes it easier to associate the type of equation with the appropriate methods.